# Load test kubernetes cluster with Jmeter and Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, prometheus, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a kubernetes cluster and I want to do load testing on it using Jmeter and Prometheus. I have setup Jmeter on separate EC2 instance and I am getting response from cluster when I run jmx script. Prometheus is running inside cluster and I want to push Jmeter metrics to Prometheus but I am not able to do this. My question is, if Jmeter is running outside kubernetes cluster and Prometheus is running inside kubernetes cluster, can Prometheus scrape Jmeter to collect metrics or I need to run Jmeter within kubernetes cluster to do this.

Comment: How are you pushing the metrics and what error arr you getting while doing so.

Comment: I am using jmeter prometheus exporter. I don't get any error but no metrics are pushed to Prometheus.

Comment: What is the target in your jmeter job ?

Comment: IP address of EC2 instance followed by port (9270)

Comment: go inside the pod and check if you can reach the IP you mentioned.

Comment: Ok and by I assume by pod you mean Prometheus pod, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218957/discussion-between-tarun-khosla-and-balkrishan-nagpal).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user didn't post any update, there're no answers, but only comments, which are not adding anything helpful to other users. The chat doesn't contain anything relevant to other users potentially facing the same problem too.